Can't access the json data fetched from node-fetch
I have an url that I can fetch json data from. I use node-fetch to do it but after fetching the data, I could log the json object on the console but I couldn't access the elements inside it. I also got errors like TypeError: data.forEach is not a function when try to call a method since the data should be an array of RidesData
Here are the code to fetch the data :
export interface RidesData {
  coaster_name: string;
  length: string;
  speed: string;
  location: string;
  status: string;
  opening_date: string;
  type: string;
  manufacturer: string;
  height_restriction: string;
  model: string;
  height: string;
  inversions: string;
  lift_launch_system: string;
  cost: string;
  trains: string;
  park_section: string;
  duration: string;
  capacity: string;
  g_force: number;
  designer: string;
  max_vertical_angle: string;
  drop: string;
  soft_opening_date: string;
  fast_lane_available: string;
  replaced: string;
  track_layout: string;
  fastrack_available: string;
  closing_date: string;
  opened: string;
  replaced_by: string;
  website: string;
  flash_pass_available: string;
  must_transfer_from_wheelchair: string;
  theme: string;
  single_rider_line_available: string;
  restraint_style: string;
  acceleration: string;
  restraints: string;
  name: string;
  year_introduced: number;
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  type_main: string;
  opening_date_clean: string;
  speed1: string;
  speed2: string;
  speed1_value: number;
  speed1_unit: string;
  speed_mph: number;
  height_value: number;
  height_unit: string;
  height_ft: string;
  inversions_clean: number;
  gforce_clean: number;
}

// Return Promise object for asynchronous operations
export function fetchData(url: string): Promise<RidesData[]> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Dynamically import node-fetch
    import('node-fetch')
    .then(({ default: fetch }) => {
      // Make HTTP GET request
      let settings = { method: "Get" };
      fetch(url, settings)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json: RidesData[]) => {
          resolve(json);
        })
        .catch((error: Error) => { 
          reject(error);
        });
    })
    .catch((error: Error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}
```

Here is the code to access the data 

```
export const isOpened = async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  try {
    console.log("Starting isOpened");
    const coaster: string = req.params.coasterName;
    const data = await fetchData(url); // data is type RidesDataType[]
    console.log('Finished fetching data', data); // Here it'll show the whole json object
    console.log(data[0]) // Here it returned undefined
    
    let coasterExists: Boolean = false;
    let isOpened: Boolean = false;

    // Check if the coaster exists and if it's open
    // Here I have TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
    data.forEach((ride: RidesDataType) => {
      if (ride.coaster_name === coaster) {
        coasterExists = true;
        if (ride.status === 'Open') {
          isOpened = true;
        }
      }
    });

    if (!coasterExists) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Coaster not found' });
    }

    // Check if the coaster is open
    if (isOpened) {
      return res.json({ coaster, status: 'Open' });
    } else {
      return res.json({ coaster, status: 'Closed' });
    }
  } catch(error: unknown) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.sendStatus(400);
  }
}
```

I tried to log everything on the console but the json is too big so I couldn't get too much information

This is the url : https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Jurollet/12470631232f30a81ace67add5bf839a/raw/3c514d9618b98e58a870bb2f0f01fbe3221e03f5/rides.json


You're tricking TS into believing it's an array with json: RidesData[] type assertion, there's no evidence it's really an array. The error suggests the opposite. In the url you posted it's seen it's an object with "rides" property

@EstusFlask Yes that's was the problem, I'm still not familliar with TS so can I ask what do you think is a good approach for type definitions so that I won't make this mistake again ?

No type problems per se. You need to verify yourself that "data" matches the asserted type when doing this. TS types don't exist at runtime, it can only detect errors in ones that exist in code at compilation time

Your JSON data does not look to be an array of RidesData, but an object which rides property contains such array:
{
  "rides": [{
    "coaster_name": "Switchback Railway",
    "length": "600 ft (180 m)",
    "speed": "6 mph (9.7 km/h)",
    // etc.
  }]
}

Therefore you can access that list by reading said rides member:
console.log(data.rides[0])

data.rides?.forEach(/* etc. */)


You are right thank you very much !!! Btw I fixed this by creating a new type call Rides and inside is the rides property which has the type of RidesData[]. Do you think it's the correct way ?

Thank you for your kind feedback! Yes that is fine.
